# A statement on a set and its cluster

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a compact metric space and $f:X\rightarrow X$ be a homeomorphism. we define the orbit of a point $x$ as $\mathcal{O}(x)=\lbrace f^n(x): n\in\mathbb{Z}\rbrace$.let $\mu$ be the borel measure on $X$, $A\subset X$ a measurable subset with $\mu(A)>0$.Can we say that:

$\mu$-a.e. $x\in A$: $\overline{\mathcal{O}(x)}=X$$\Longleftrightarrow$ $\mu$-a.e. $x\in\overline{A}$: $\overline{\mathcal{O}(x)}=X$

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be $\{1/n : n \geq 1\} \bigcup \{2 - 1/n : n \geq 1\} \bigcup \{0, 2\}$  with usual metric and $\mu$ be a probability measure than assigns positive measure to each point. Let $f: X \rightarrow X$ be the homeomorphism that fixes $0, 2$ and shifts everything else to the right by one - So $f(1/5) = 1/4$, $f(3/2) = 5/3$ etc. Then $A = X \backslash \{0, 2\}$ is a counterexample.

Comment: thank you.But $\mu$ is a Borel measure.Maybe it was better to say that $X=M$ a compact riemannian manifold and $\mu$ the lebesgue measure.

Comment: On the real line, the orbit of any point under any homeomorphism can never be dense so your equivalence holds vacuously. I don't know what happens in other spaces but I think the answer should depend on the underlying space.

Comment: you're right. Thank you for your help.